# How to rename a dependent .as file without breaking the .swf?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm working on a flash project and wanted to rename an .as file.  When I changed the name, the .swf breaks.  Is there anyway I can remap the .as file to the .fla from CS5.5?

Also, I'm new to actionscript and flash and just wanted to know where is it preferred to keep your .as files?  I've seen examples where people store them in a separate folder (ex. Actionscript/MainTimeline.as) but I've also seen examples where people just keep all the .as in their .fla file.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "the .swf breaks"? What is it exactly you are trying to do? Change a class file name?

Comment: @JonatanHedborg Sure!  So I when I rename MainTimeline.as to abc123.as, and I compile a new .swf, the .swf doesn't work.  I trying to change the filename of the .as file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would store them in an unique folder and its subfolders if needed. If you want to do this you will have to open the ActionScript Settings panel and add the new folder to "Source Path", so Flash knows where to find the as files when compiling.

You can rename an external .as file, but you will have to rename the class inside this file:

```
 public class ClassName //class declaration
```

...

```
public function ClassName() //constructor
```

Then you will have to change every reference to this class in your fla. First look in the AS3 code written on frames.

Finally you may have to remap clip linked to these classes (if there are any). Go into your symbol's property and change the field "Class".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly: when you rename the AS file, you also need to rename the class contained within, and update the reference in the IDE to the new class name.